# Chromecast default receiver thumbnail size

Tags: image, size, chromecast

Can anyone tell me the dimensions of the thumbnail image rendered by the Chromecast default receiver? I can't find this documented anywhere, and my current images are squashed. (I guess I could find out by trial and error, but if there's an official answer I'd love to have it.)

Cheers

Nic

Answer (score 0):

It is actually in the [developer docs](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/styled_receiver):
*Note: The video image art is 96x143 pixels and the first image resource associated with the media metadata is selected for display. Images are scaled to fit the expected dimensions*

Comment: Thanks, but that seems to be for the styled receiver rather than the default one. Those docs note that the video image is 96x143, while the image for audio album art is 384x384 - neither of which looks like the aspect ration I'm seeing on the thumbnail in the default receiver. Thanks very much for the reply, though.

Comment: The default receiver is the same as the Styled receiver, the only difference is that there is no css-customization for you in the default receiver.

Comment: Well, that's great - but it still doesn't answer the actual question since nether set of dimensions fits the aspect ratio observed in thumbnails in the default receiver. Thanks though.